# Problem in Reading MpegTs File with VLC

Tags: video, mpeg2-ts

I have written an encoder for mpegts and I am trying to play it using VLC,but VLC is not able to play my file.
My encoder looks fine as it is writting PAT, PMT tables, video data properly.
Could any one please help me, what could be the major issue?

This is the log I got from VLC:

```
main debug: processing request item Record.mpg node Playlist skip 0
main debug: resyncing on Record.mpg
main debug: Record.mpg is at 0
main debug: starting new item
main debug: creating new input thread
main debug: Creating an input for 'Record.mpg'
main debug: thread (input) created at priority 1 (../.././src/input/input.c:214)
main debug: thread started
main debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
main debug: using timeshift path 'C:\DOCUME~1\User\LOCALS~1\Temp'
main debug: `file:///E:/RecordFiles/Record.mpg' gives access `file' demux `' path `E:\RecordFiles\Record.mpg'
main debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='' path='E:\RecordFiles\Record.mpg'
main debug: looking for access_demux module: 2 candidates
main debug: no access_demux module matching "file" could be loaded
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.000 ms - Total 0.000 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.000 ms)
main debug: creating access 'file' path='E:\RecordFiles\Record.mpg'
main debug: looking for access module: 2 candidates
filesystem debug: opening file `E:\RecordFiles\Record.mpg'
main debug: using access module "filesystem"
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.000 ms - Total 0.000 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.000 ms)
main debug: Using AStream*Stream
main debug: pre buffering
main debug: received first data after 0 ms
main debug: pre-buffering done 1024 bytes in 0s - 1000000 KiB/s
main debug: looking for stream_filter module: 2 candidates
main debug: no stream_filter module matching "any" could be loaded
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 3.000 ms - Total 3.000 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 3.000 ms)
main debug: looking for stream_filter module: 1 candidate
main debug: using stream_filter module "stream_filter_record"
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.000 ms - Total 0.000 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.000 ms)
main debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='' path='E:\RecordFiles\Record.mpg'
main debug: looking for demux module: 50 candidates
ts debug: pid[16] unknown
ts debug: pid[32] unknown
qt4 debug: IM: Setting an input
ts debug: eof ?
main debug: using demux module "ts"
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 67.000 ms - Total 67.000 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 67.000 ms)
main debug: looking for a subtitle file in E:\RecordFiles\
ts debug: DEMUX_SET_GROUP 0 00000000
main debug: looking for meta reader module: 2 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Documents and Settings\User\Application Data\vlc\lua\meta\reader
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\reader
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\reader\filename.lua
main debug: no meta reader module matching "any" could be loaded
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.000 ms - Total 0.000 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.000 ms)
main debug: `file:///E:/RecordFiles/Record.mpg' successfully opened
ts debug: eof ?
main debug: EOF reached
main debug: finished input
ts debug: pid list:
ts debug:   - pid[0] seen
ts debug:   - pid[16] seen
ts debug:   - pid[32] seen
ts debug:   - pid[8191] seen
main debug: removing module "ts"
main debug: removing module "stream_filter_record"
main debug: removing module "filesystem"
main debug: dead input
main debug: thread ended
main debug: thread times: real 0m0.078125s, kernel 0m0.046875s, user 0m0.031250s
main debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
main debug: nothing to play
qt4 debug: IM: Deleting the input
main debug: TIMER input launching for 'Record.mpg' : 70.000 ms - Total 70.000 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 70.000 ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me but I do see two unknown pids, and VLC thinks there's nothing to do.  So potentially playable packets, if actually present in your TS, are being ignored because it can't associate the pid with a decoder.  Find a Transport Stream viewer program and compare your TS with other known working ones, looking for differences.

Comment: Hi wberry,Thank you for the quick response.I found the problem.Its due to CRC in PMT and PAT.Some how my CRC generator is not working.I have used the following method but still CRC is not correctly generated....... "int GetCrc32(char *pBuff, S32 nLength) { boost::crc_32_type result; result.process_bytes(pBuff, nLength); return result.checksum(); } "